# Is it possible to have synchronized charts with error lines?

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to have synchronized-charts that would show error bars too? I have 3 timeseries I'd like to show in a synchronized-charts, but each measurement has a +-3% of error and would like to show that too but without the bars. Similar to https://ibb.co/4jL7ZZ0

Is this achievable? If so how?

Thanks.

Comment: I think that you can start from this demo: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/synchronized-charts, but I am not sure what you have in mind by saying the: `show error bars too`. Could you describe it more precisely or add some image of the wanted output?

Comment: Each point in a time series has a margin of error associated with it. So if I have a data point in 2008 and it's y = 15m, this xy point has a margin of error +-3%. I'd like to show this error too. I've posted a URL to the image of what I'd like to achieve in the original post too - https://ibb.co/4jL7ZZ0. Hopefully this helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the clarification. I think that you can use the `errorbar` series type to achieve it.

Demo: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/error-bar

Comment: Thanks. I'll read the `errorbar` to see if it's possible to have 3 synced plots in one like the synchronized-charts.